# Ресайз Bitmap в пропорции

Tags: c#, bitmap, resize, bitmapimage

Как правильнее ресайзить изображение в формате Bitmap, с учётом:

Есть `мастер` Bitmap, предположим размером 1261х760.
Есть `регион` Bitmap, это Rectangle с `мастера` размером 100х100 снятый с координат `мастера` например w=120, h=240.

Вот как правильнее сделать ресайз `регион` Bitmap и пересчитать кооординаты `мастер` Bitmap, где находится `регион`, с учётом что `мастер` Bitmap изменил размеры например на 866х420, то есть пропорции мастера сохраняются.

Это надо для дальнейшего сравнения регионов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
W_ratio = new_width / old_width
H_ratio = new_height / old_height

new_Xpos = old_Xpos * W_ratio
new_region_width = old_region_width * W_ratio
```

и аналогично для y и высоты

Comment: Ух, спасибо :) заклинило, хотя все как на ладони.